# How to understand the design of fire() and send() in mapbox-gl

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

#### How could I get relations between all the modules and how would they work together?

mapbox-gl-js version:v0.28.0

I find it's difficult to debug and analyse the code of mapbox-gl for me. Most of time fire() and send() are used to organize the function calling. **I find its difficult for me to seek out which function is callar and which is callee.** Is there any good way to understand the design of mapbox-gl more efficiently?
By the way, where can I find architecture diagram or UML of Mapbox-gl. It'll be very helpful, I believe.

e.g.

`this.dispatcher.send('reloadTile', params, done.bind(this), tile.workerID);`

`this.fire('load');`

`

```
fire(type, data) {
    if (this.listens(type)) {

        data = util.extend({}, data, {type: type, target: this});

        // make sure adding or removing listeners inside other listeners won't cause an infinite loop
        const listeners = this._listeners && this._listeners[type] ? this._listeners[type].slice() : [];

        for (let i = 0; i < listeners.length; i++) {
            listeners[i].call(this, data);
        }

        if (this._eventedParent) {
            this._eventedParent.fire(type, util.extend({}, data, this._eventedParentData));
        }

    // To ensure that no error events are dropped, print them to the
    // console if they have no listeners.
    } else if (util.endsWith(type, 'error')) {
        console.error((data && data.error) || data || 'Empty error event');
    }

    return this;
}
```

`

Answer (score 1):

`fire` is used as part of the [`Evented`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#Evented) implementation to deliver information about events as they are happening. `send` is used to transfer data between the worker and main threads and should not be needed in client side applications using Mapbox GL JS.

We do not have an architecture diagram per se, but we are actively developing more detailed documentation about the architecture [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/pull/4066)

*Disclaimer - I work at Mapbox*